# Is there any solution for maven dependency of common-collections4.1 instead of adding jar file to build path to projec

Tags: java, maven

Getting and error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap
at ReadXLS.readexcel(ReadXLS.java:27)
at exceldataread.main(exceldataread.java:9)
```

however added maven dependency of `common-collection4` version 4.1 to project but when i am adding the jar file then no error shown and project run successful.

Answer (score 2):

The correct dependency is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @NishantOmar what means *is not working* any error message? Have you rebuild the project

Comment: Yes throwing “Exception in thread ”main“ java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap”, yes even after rebuild the project getting the same error

Comment: @NishantOmar Show your whole pom please